# Failing Prerequisites installer - WCF Data Service 5.6

Tags: sharepoint-server, prerequisites

I want to try the new SharePoint Subscription Edition for on-prem environments. But unfortunately the pre requisites installer cant download the required WCF Data Services 5.6. I believe this is part of the prerequisites for SP2016 and SP2019 but it seems that the download got deleted from the Microsoft download center. I found some posts about this issues back in 2019 where it got restored, but it looks like Microsoft removed it again.

Does anyone know a way to get that download?

```
2021-08-27 12:47:18 - Installing Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.6.
2021-08-27 12:47:18 - WCF Data Services 5.6 local install path is NULL. Try to download from FWLink.
2021-08-27 12:47:18 - Beginning download of Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.6
2021-08-27 12:47:18 - https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=320724
2021-08-27 12:47:20 - Size of download of "Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.6" in bytes is "1213"
2021-08-27 12:47:20 - Download of "Microsoft WCF Data Services 5.6" completed successfully
2021-08-27 12:47:20 - Error: The digital signature of "C:\Users\ADMINS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\WCFBFF7.tmp.exe" is invalid (-1)
2021-08-27 12:47:20 - Error: Failed to download WCF Data Services 5.6 installation package, (0X800700B7=-2147024713)
2021-08-27 12:47:20 - Last return code (-1)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could download it from the archives:
https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/C/A/1CAA41C7-88B9-42D6-9E11-3C655656DAB1/WcfDataServices.exe

For Reference: [WCF Data Services 5.6 Q&A forum](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/530781/wcf-data-services-56.html)